# Merging functions with similar content, but different parameters

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Given the following (pseudo)code:

```
typedef std::map<const unsigned int, unsigned long int> ModelVector;
typedef std::vector<unsigned long int> EncryptedVector;

int test1 (const EncryptedVector &x)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    data = kenel1(x, y);
    //compute output
}
int test2 (const EncryptedVector &xx)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    data = kenel2(xx, y);
    //compute output
}
int test3 (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    data = kenel3(x, xx, y);
    //compute output
}
int test4 (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xSquared)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    data = kenel4(x, xSquared, y);
    //compute output
}
```

Because the variables y and output are computed identically in all 4 functions and since I have a "global" object which allows me to select the appropriate kernel function via a switch statement, I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to write them, preferably merging them somehow...

For example, something like this (pseudocode) would be a decent choice:

```
int test (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx, const EncryptedVector &xSquared)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    //switch (kernel) -> select the appropriate one
    //compute output
}

test (x, NULL, NULL);//test1
test (NULL, xx, NULL);//test2
test (x, xx, NULL);//test3
test (x, NULL, xSquared);//test4
```

Or, even better, I could declare test multiple times with different parameter combinations, all falling back on the one above (even though I would loose the semantic distinction between x and xx).

The problem with the above approach is that C++ doesn't allow me to pass NULL instead of std::vector and I think I'm better off repeating the code 4 times than to start passing variables by pointer instead of passing them by reference...

Is there any other way of doing this?

---

EDIT: Here are the prototypes for the kernel functions:

```
int kernel1 (const EncryptedVector &x, const ModelVector &y);
int kernel2 (const EncryptedVector &xx, const ModelVector &y);
int kernel3 (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx, const ModelVector &y);
int kernel4 (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xSquared, const ModelVector &y);
```

Comment: Tangential -- Free functions cannot be `const`.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I have them inside a class :D

Comment: How would the `kernel` be selected in your proposed code?

Comment: And can you provide prototypes for the 4 different `kernel` functions?

Comment: @JohnDibling Well, since these functions are actually methods inside a class (I did not want to overcomplicate the pseudocode), I have a private member that contains the appropriate kernel, which is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @JohnDibling I added the prototypes for the kernel fucntions. I have an enum which contains all the possible kernel types and I could use a switch on the private member, to select the appropriate kernel function.

Comment: OK, that took me some time to get written.  Please see my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original 4 `test` methods select a different behavior (eg, a different `kernel` function is called) based not on the *types* of the arguments passed, but by the *semantics* of the arguments passed.  Not to metion the fact they have entirely different names.

If you could somehow change this parameterization from a semantic one to one of a type, you could use your proposed method of combining all 4 methods in to one.

This means having one function with all 3 parameters, which is exactly what you've proposed:

```
int test (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx, const EncryptedVector &xSquared)
```

...the problem of course  being you can't pass `NULL` by reference.  You need to pass an actual `vector`.  You could pass an empty, temporary vector, like this:

```
test (x, EncryptedVector(), EncryptedVector());  //test1
```

...and then select the method internally based on the `empty()` state of the passed in `vector`:

```
int test (const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx, const EncryptedVector &xSquared)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    //switch (kernel) -> select the appropriate one
      if( xx.empty() && xSquared.empty() )
      {
        // kenel1 method
      }
      else if( x.empty() && xSquared.empty() )
      {
        // kenel2 method
      }
      else if( ... etc ... )

    //compute output
}
```

And perhaps for your uses this is sufficient, but the above raises at least a couple new issues.

One is the chain of `if` statements.  This introduces complexity, both in factors of execution time, and perhaps more importantly in terms of maintainability.  I know I wouldn't want to maintain 4 pages of `if` statements.

Other issues include the clumsy invocation of the method with empty `vector`s, and the fact that you can still call `test` with an invalid combination of `vector`s.

So, getting back to using a type-based selection of behavior rather than a semantic one.  What if you didn't specify a concrete type for `test()`'s parameters, but a `template` instead?

```
template<class VectorX, class VectorXX, class VectorXSquared>
int test(const VectorX& x, const VectorXX& xx, const VectorXSquared& xSquared);
```

Now you can also provide a special `NullVector` type:

```
class NullVector {}; // Empty Class
```

... and then explicitly specialize the `test` function for each of your valid use cases (above, you have listed 4 valid use cases).

Invocation of `test` now becomes something like this:

```
test(x,NullVector(),NullVector());  // First Use Case
```

This also has an added benefit.  If you do not provide an implementation for the non-specialized version of `test`, any attempt to call `test` with invalid parameters will fail to compile & link.  For example, in your listed use cases, none of them take 3 valid `EncryptedVector` objects, so this should fail to compile:

```
test(x, xx, xSquared);
```

...which, indeed, it will if you don't provide a non-specialized implemtation of `test`.

OK, that's a lot of talking and maybe it wasn't all well explained.  So here is a complete sample that I hope will help illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<string> EncryptedVector;

class NullVector{}; // Empty Class

int kernel1(const EncryptedVector& x)
{
    return 1;
}

int kernel2(const EncryptedVector& xx)
{
    return 2;
}

int kernel3(const EncryptedVector& x, const EncryptedVector& xx)
{
    return 3;
}

int kernel4(const EncryptedVector& x, const EncryptedVector& xSquared)
{
    return 4;
}

template<class VectorX, class VectorXX, class VectorXSquared> 
int test(const VectorX& x, const VectorXX& xx, const VectorXSquared& xSquared);

template<> int test<>(const EncryptedVector& x, const NullVector&, const NullVector&)
{
    return kernel1(x);
}

template<> int test<>(const NullVector&, const EncryptedVector& xx, const NullVector&)
{
    return kernel2(xx);
}

template<> int test<>(const EncryptedVector& x, const EncryptedVector& xx, const NullVector&)
{
    return kernel3(x, xx);
}

template<> int test<>(const EncryptedVector &x, const NullVector&, const EncryptedVector &xSquared)
{
    return kernel4(x,xSquared);
}

int main()
{
    EncryptedVector x, xx, xSquared;  // each somehow populated

    ///*** VALID USE-CASES ***///
    test(x,NullVector(),NullVector());
    test(NullVector(),xx,NullVector());
    test(x,xx,NullVector());
    test(x,NullVector(),xSquared);

    ///*** INVALID USE CASES WILL FAIL TO COMPILE&LINK ***///
    test(x,xx,xSquared);

}
```

Comment: Thanks John. That is a really nice solution to my design issue.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's always fun to solve problems a little bigger than just "why did I get a segafult here?" :)

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I want to become a software architect, on the long run :) and I've been bashing my head against the wall with this all day, because I'm new to C++ (I'll probably still be a n00b to it for the next year or so, since it's such a complex language) and I have a hard time getting accustomed with templates...

Answer (score 0):

You could send an object (it's called functor, if i'm not mistaken) that contains the additional parameters and has a function that calculates the kernel (kenel?).

```
// Main function, looks more generic now
template <class F>
int test1234(F functor)
{
    //compute ModelVector y
    data = functor(y);
    //compute output
}

...

// Functors involve some tedious coding, but at least your main calculation is clean
struct functor_for_kernel1
{
    const EncryptedVector &x;
    functor_for_kernel1(const EncryptedVector &x): x(x) {}
    int operator(const ModelVector &y) {return kernel1(x, y);
};

struct functor_for_kernel2 // easy
...

struct functor_for_kernel3
{
    const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx;
    functor_for_kernel3(const EncryptedVector &x, const EncryptedVector &xx): x(x), xx(xx) {}
    int operator()(const ModelVector &y) {return kernel3(x, xx, y);
};

struct functor_for_kernel4 // easy
...

// Usage of the unified function
test1234(functor_for_kernel1(x));
test1234(functor_for_kernel2(xx));
test1234(functor_for_kernel3(x, xx));
test1234(functor_for_kernel4(x, xx));
```

Comment: Although this approach is also valid, I'd rather go with John's suggestion, because it's cleaner and it involves less coding.